# Running OClint in Xcode bots

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode-bots

Hey i want to run oclint using Xcode bots.
Currently what i am doing is runing oclint as a post build run script. 
But it is always unable to find the provisioning profile.

Here is what i am doing

```
xcodebuild -target MyTarget -configuration Debug clean build | tee xcodebuild.log
oclint-xcodebuild
oclint-json-compilation-database  -- -max-priority-1 99999 -max-priority-2 99999 -max-priority-3 99999
```

and this is the output that i get from the xcode bot

```
[BEROR]Code Sign error: No matching provisioning profile found: Your build settings specify a provisioning profile with the UUID “6F753CA0-4435-40FF-B2F4-15B64D0F7AEE”, however, no such provisioning profile was found.
[BEROR]CodeSign error: code signing is required for product type 'Application' in SDK 'iOS 7.1'
```

Although normal builds without oclint work fine.

Answer (score 0):

I had this error, and if you switch the provisioning profile to Automatic it will build successfully on the Xcode Bot. However, this may not work for actually building your project, but it should get the bot working for you to verify that there isn't another issue with it.